# React native android TransactionTooLargeException

Tags: android, react-native, transactiontoolargeexception

We recently released a ReactNative application, but we're receiving many crash reports on android with `java.lang.RuntimeExceptionBinder.java` `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size X(between 400k to 750k) bytes`.

On our app we have an infinite scrolling list (Flatlist), which can get quite big (2k + records), which is suspected to be causing this issue.
I've seen https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19458 opened, but with no solution.
Also using the suggested tool (TooLargeTool) in there points that 0 bytes are saved when going to the background.

Have anybody gone through this issue or have any input on how to fix it?

Thank you